# Return mean of several variables through iteration using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to calculate the mean of several variables after iterating many times. My function creates random data, and from those, I calculate the variables (using other functions).

So far I have:

```
stuff1_list = []
stuff2_list = []
stuff3_list = []
for i in range(100):
    data = create_data(arg1, arg2)
    stuff1_list.append(calc_stuff1(data))
    stuff2_list.append(calc_stuff2(data))
    stuff3_list.append(calc_stuff3(data))
mean1 = np.mean(stuff1_list)
mean2 = np.mean(stuff2_list)
mean3 = np.mean(stuff3_list)
```

I've been trying to figure out how to do this with multiprocessing, but I am confused with Process, Queue, Pool, and so on. How can I get this job done with parallel processing?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

```py
def do_stuff():
    stuff_list = []
    for i in range(100):
        data = create_data(arg1, arg2)
        stuff_list.append(calc_stuff(data))
    print(np.mean(stuff_list))

for i in range(3):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_stuff, args=())
    p.start()
```

Comment: would the number 3 in "for i in range(3):" be the number of cores? And just to clarify, I need to generate new data in every iteration, so it should go inside the loop "range(100)".

Comment: 3 will be the amount of processes you have, they can run on the same or different cores.
Do you want to run all of your routines on the same data? This implementation calls `create_data` for each routine independently.

Comment: OK re number 3, thanks! Re the data, it is randomized data, so it is important that I create new data for each of the 100 times. Then, I calculate the variables only once for that data.

Comment: If `create_data` returns new data on each call then it should be fine.

Comment: OK. It is just that I don't understand how  `creata_data` is being called 100 times if it is outside the `range(100)` loop. Am I missing something related to the way `multiprocessing.Process` works?